# Hide selected TabIItems in WPF TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I'm using the TabControl in WPF as a sort of equivalent to the ASP.Net multiview control. I need to make two of the four tabitem headers hidden. What would be the best method of doing this in XAML?

Comment: Feel free to update your question, or add additional information if this is not the answer that you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by adding DataTriggers to my Template. If my tab is DeTached (Hidden) I set the `Visibility` property to `Collapsed`. If it's visiable again I simply set the `Visibility` property to `Visible` again.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDetached}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDetached}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Edit: Updated based on `@Miklós Balogh` feedback. Thanks, improved my code as well, haha. :)

Comment: Set instead the Visibility of the TabItem: `<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />`